# Does Mint.com have an API to download data? If not, are any scraping tools available?

Tags: mint.com

I have been using mint.com for some time to track my personal finances, and I'd like to be able to download my data so I can perform more in-depth analysis than what is provided on the site.  Mint.com also lost a good chunk of my data recently, and their customer service is less than stellar, so I'd like to keep a copy locally.

Obviously, an API provided by mint.com would be ideal, but as far as I know there isn't one available.  Let me know if I've missed that.

A second option is to write a script that authenticates to mint.com and scrapes the site periodically.  Has anybody attempted to do this (in any language on any platform)?  I have a feeling it would be a little more difficult than sending a password to a login page and saving the session cookie returned in the response.

A third option is to write a plugin (firefox or chrome) that saves the data when I am logged in and looking at the site.

I figure that other people have attempted to get their data out of mint, so I thought I'd ask before putting in the time to do it myself.

Comment: Do you really need an API? What are you looking for that the "Export all transactions" link doesn't give you.

Comment: automation... non tech savvy users can't export all transactions, they wouldn't know how, and imagine how much trouble it is if you have 10 accounts... to do that every time you'd probably rather just not bother

Comment: Purely from a automation standpoint.  I'd prefer to not have to download the csv's manually (transactions page, various trends pages, etc) on a regular basis.  Also, they don't expose everything that way (though to be honest, all I really care about is transactions and net worth).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mint does not have an API.

Comment: Thanks, I saw these but figured that mint may have edited away any posts from people that have put together authentication automation scripts.  Looks like I'll probably just code it up myself.

Answer (score 16):

I've written a small scraping library here: https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi. It can be used from Python, or outputs JSON from the command-line for use anywhere. It works with Mint.com as of today (2/18/2013).

Comment: Looks promising, however doesn't seem to work. :( Gives invalid syntax on the very last line - "print json.dumps".

Comment: Sorry @Justin, it didn't have Python 3 support at the time, though now it does :)

Answer (score 5):

> A second option is to write a script that authenticates to mint.com and
>   scrapes the site periodically. Has anybody attempted to do this (in any
>   language on any platform)?

Here is a Ruby script I wrote that does this: https://github.com/toddmazierski/mint-exporter

> I have a feeling it would be a little more difficult than sending a password
>   to a login page and saving the session cookie returned in the response.

Thankfully it's not — that's exactly how the script works! :-)

Comment: Here's one written in bash: [https://github.com/jchavannes/mintreport](https://github.com/jchavannes/mintreport). It can also import into  MySQL and email reports. I have it cron'd to run once a day at 8am.

Answer (score 5):

Intuit now exposed API's that mint uses underneath. Check out the "Customer Account Data" information at 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs. That page also has other API's that Intuit exposes.

Comment: From what I can tell, this API costs a minimum of $1k per month to use.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a screen scraping API though [Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com).

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that Yodlee provided an API.  I may try them out.

Comment: You're wasting your time, Yodlee charges per account added when using their API.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in a Google spreadsheet "application" I created. I call it Mojito. :-)

Mojito directly imports your transactions from Mint.com and allows you to create budgets using any combination of categories and tags. It's not intended to replace Mint.com, but rather act as a companion. Feel free to check it out and share it with others.

You can find more information and get a copy of the spreadsheet here: http://b3devs.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

Mint does not have an API anymore… it’s been shut down…

Here is a [link](https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1370157-i-am-also-looking-specifically-for-the-mint-api) to someone asking the same question to Intuit who now owns mint.

Here is a blog post with more info about them not having it.

[Intuit Financial Data APIs (CAD) Update - Intuit Developer Community Blog](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2016/03/15/intuit-financial-data-apis-cad-update)

Comment: please add essential contents of the link into answer. It would be helpful to the future reader.

Answer (score 0):

Since mint is not available in the EU yet, there is a solution with a direct access through the figo Banking API.
If someone is interested in financial data from banks and other financial sources in the EU, I would check out www.figo.io
API-Access will be granted with a request here: http://figo.io/api_key.html